# Magento : add a button to the edit product page accessible to a specific resource acl

Tags: magento, button, admin, acl, product

I tried to override the block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit and I create the button "delete_cache_product" this way:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->_product = $this->getProduct();
        $this->setChild('delete_cache_product',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('delete cache'),
                'onclick'   => 'confirmSetLocation(\''.Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?').'\', \''.$this->getDeleteCacheProductUrl().'\')',
                'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete product cache?')
            ))
        );
    return $this;
}
```

the problem is how can I associate a resource acl for that button so that only users who have access to such resources can see the button???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solutio.: I create a permission in `adminhtml.xml` and I call directly:

```
# File: adminhtml.xml
<config>
    <acl>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <catalog>
                    <children>
                        <products>
                            <children>
                                <deletecacheproduct>
                                    <title>Delete product cache</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </deletecacheproduct>
                            </children>
                        </products>
                    </children>
                </catalog>
            </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

---

```
# File: Edit.php (block)

if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/products/deletecacheproduct')) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom admin module with an ACL then

```
 if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/custommodulename')){
    $this->setChild('delete_cache_product',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('delete cache'),
            'onclick'   => 'confirmSetLocation(\''.Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Are you sure?').'\', \''.$this->getDeleteCacheProductUrl().'\')',
            'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete product cache?')
        ))
    );
 }
```

See http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but there is any way to do it without creating a new admin module?

Comment: If you dont create a new admin module, where/how will you set the permission ?

Comment: Now, to add the button, i'm using catalog module to override the block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit : I wonder if there is a way to assign permission to the block instead of a new module??